# Hibernate C3P0: Checking out connection and releasing it

Tags: hibernate, c3p0

I am trying to obtain Connections from Hibernate C3P0 as follows:

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource; // ComboPooledDataSource

public Connection getConnection() {
    dataSource.getConnection();
}
```

This is correctly working. What I am unsure of is releasing/closing these connections.

Do I need to call `connection.close()`? I just want the connection to be put back to pool and not closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to close the connection. Closing a pooled connection is what gives it back to the pool. It doesn't actually close the physical connection.

Closing it in a finally block (or better, using try-with-resources) is critical, otherwise your pool will quickly go out of available connections.

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly what I wanted to know. I have a one last strange issue: even when I properly close the connection, when executing 100 queries where each of them checks out new connection, after a while I receive "Lock timeout exceeded" – the queries are not run in parallel and this should probably not happen. Also there are no queries running according to `show processlist`.

Comment: That should be another question, containing the code and the complete stack trace of the exception.